# NodeJS http module: what is requestListener?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to JS and more specifically Node. Even after reading the api docs, I'm confused about what 'requestListener' is in the following method.

```
http.createServer([requestListener]);
```

Searching google revealed that 'requestListener' is a(n) (anonymous) function with the following signature:

```
function (request, response) { };
```

I suppose I'm reading the docs incorrectly, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand about it?

Comment: I don't understand why requestListener must have that specific signature (those two parameters).

Comment: As a side-note - in JS, all function parameters are basically optional, so you could, in theory, provide a function that does not take any arguments. However, you would then have no way of responding to the request! Also, the docs say that the function is simply attached to the `request` event, so taking a look at the [request event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) reveals what params the function will receive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [docs say](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) that the method call takes a function which will be called when a new request is received by your application. This function, as you correctly stated in your question, takes two arguments - a `request` and `response` objects.

You should inspect the contents of these objects to learn what information is available to you. Also, take a look at the API docs for [request](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) and [response](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).

The function is optional; you could also attach the request handler in the following way:

```
var server = http.createServer()

server.on('request', function (req, res) {
  // Process the request here
})
```

In practice, this function is called when someone opens up your website in their browser (i.e. issues a GET http request). The purpose of that function is to provide a HTTP response body back to the client, i.e. render a web page or perform any business logic as necessary.

Comment: does it make "requestListener" a middleware in express terminology?

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question: it's a function that gets called when a request is received by the server and is given those two parameters.

At the very least you can experiment with doing a `console.log(request, response)` inside the function and see what is spit out in your terminal.

But that's only the beginning of the rabbit hole. You should read up on "callback functions", as they are integral to how Node (and quite a bit of client-side javascript) operates (asynchronously).

Comment: Thanks, I've been practicing with anonymous functions in 'learnyounode' exercises. What I don't understand is -how- I'm supposed to know what signature the function has, as it isn't clear in the docs.

Comment: This function is not called when the server is created; it is called when a request is received by the http server.

Comment: ahh, yeah, that can be a bit confusing. in the absence of any formal documentation for these types of things, `console.log` is your friend. you can set arbitrary parameters for the callback function and just see what they are.

Answer (score 0):

The `http.createServer` method creates a [server](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen) object.

The `server` object has a [listen](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen) method. If you invoke the `listen` method, for example:

```
createServer(requestListener).listen({ port:80 });
```

the `server` object will be listening on port 80, and when a Http request is received on that port, the `server` object will invoke the function `requestListener`, passing it two objects, of type `request` and [response](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen). So you can write your `requestListener` like, for example:

```
function requestListener(req, res) {
   res.write("Hello world");
   res.end();
}
```

and it will push out the string `Hello world` to *every* url that is hitting your this simple web server.

[write](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) is one of the many methods of the `response` object.

You can run the above few lines of code on your PC, and point your browser to http://localhost.

If you have other applications listening on port 80, then use a different port number in your `listen` method.

Using an anonymous function for `requestListener` is merely a different coding pattern, for better or for worse. My code above can be re-written as:

```
createServer((req, res) => {
   res.write("Hello world");
   res.end();
}).listen({ port:80 });
```

The above code is very rudimentary and will send the same response to every Http request that hits it. The code does not differentiate between localhost/page1 or localhost/page2, etc. So to do anything more, the `requestListener` have to be expanded significantly to parse different paths in the url and to decide on what content to send for each. But to do anything useful as a real web server without writing too much code, you will need a package. [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) is an excellent one that drives many real life web servers.

Comment: const http = require('http');

function rqListener(req,res) {
   res.write("Hello world");
   res.end();

}

http.createServer(rqListener);

this code doesn't give me any output when I hit http://localhost. I am very new to nodejs

Comment: @Chinmoy You need to first invoke the `listen` function, so `http.createServer(rqListener).listen(8080)` for example. Do not use port 80 if you are on Windows. Windows blocks port 80.