# What is function createServer(requestListener?: RequestListener):server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to NodeJS.
I am not very familiar with this statement:`function createServer(requestListener?: RequestListener):server`. Why does this method have `:server`, and why are the parameters inside not separated by commas, but uses `?:`?

Any ideas on how to fix this problem

Comment: Can you share the source of where specifically you’re seeing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is either TypeScript, or type notation included in documentation. It is not valid JavaScript code.

```
function createServer(requestListener?: RequestListener): Server;
```

means that `createServer` can accept a parameter - if a parameter is passed, the parameter must of type [`RequestListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749522/nodejs-http-module-what-is-requestlistener) (which is a callback). The question mark there indicates that the parameter is optional; `createServer` can also be called with no parameters at all.

The colon after the parameter list indicates the return type of the function. If you call `createServer`, you will get something of type [`Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) in return.

Comment: When I use proto，WebSocketServer  on('connectionrequest', fn(info, accept, reject))，What does fn mean in the parameter？

Comment: Sounds like it might mean that the second parameter should be a callback; a function that takes 3 parameters, info, accept, and reject, maybe. Or maybe `fn` is a function that's already defined, there isn't enough context to say